# Python way to search for file in sys.path

Tags: python, path

I would like to put my media and config files into a place where the Python program can find it from the working tree or from being installed. So in [that question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/212714/22584), it was suggested to put the stuff into the path. Is there some ready made function to search in the path?

If not, I will just make my own.

Comment: If so try using `os.walk` else `os.listdir`, over `sys.path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there's any python function to do this in the standard library. It should be very easy to write a function that searches each directory in `sys.path` for a file though.

A heavyweight alternative that may be suitable would be to look at packaging your module as a python package using [`setuptools`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/index.html) and  and using [`pkg_resources.ResourceManager`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) to load files from the package.

Comment: I looked into setuptools, then into the whole hell of distutils, setuptools, distribute and so on. I tried setuptools, found that Kubuntu 13.04 only has 0.6, and has some unicode problem. I guess I will just try the path version for now.